# How to add the toggle switch button from flutter to firebase firestore database

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to set up a toggle switch button from flutter to firestore. I have already set up the dependencies in my flutter project, however, I do not know how to connect the switch with the firestore.

I am trying to make an on/off switch which can be used to control light; I have tried giving it some values but, even then, I am not sure how to connect with firestore.

```
class _HomeState extends State<Home> {

 bool _value = false;

  void _onChanged(bool value) {
   setState(() {
    _value = value; 
   });

  }



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Home ${widget.user.email}'),
      ),
      body: new Container(
        padding: new EdgeInsets.all(32.0),
        child: new Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            new SwitchListTile.adaptive(
                title: new Text('Bedroom light'),
                activeColor: Colors.red,
                secondary: const Icon(Icons.lightbulb_outline),
                value: _value,
                onChanged: (bool value) {
                  _onChanged(value);

                })
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is the code I have so far. I know that we have to use StreamBuilder but I would like to know how.

Comment: Did you check the example on firestore package ?https://pub.dev/packages/cloud_firestore

Comment: yes i did check the firestore package however, i did not find out how if i switch off the light so that it will also change in firestore.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a database reference first in firestore say-

```
databaseReference = Firestore.instance.collection('Switches').where('switch','==',/*ANY NAME*/);
```

And then run a transition to update the value of value

```
Firestore.instance.runTransaction((transaction) async {
    await transaction.update(
    documentReference, _value);
};
```

Just make sure that in the firestore, the field which will take the value of `_value` is`boolean`